# Ansible variable precedence

Tags: ansible

So I have this playbook, in this playbook I have a variable, let's call it `the_var`
Now this variable should always have the same value `default` except for certain inventories where it should be `not_default`

This is how I did it, under `group_vars/all.yml` I put `the_var: default` and under `inventories/my_special_inv` I put `the_var=not_default` (under `[all:vars]`)

When I run `ansible-playbook -i inventories/my_special_inv` I expect the variables value to be `not_default` (since I overrode the default behaviour with the inventory file). but it is set to `default`

How do I implement this behaviour correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you working example that will help you to understand it better:

```
.
|-- default
|   |-- group_vars
|   |   `-- server.yml
|   `-- inventory
|-- site.yml
|-- special
|   |-- group_vars
|   |   `-- server.yml
|   `-- inventory
```

In this example I have just tested it against the localhost host so inside both the `special/inventory` and `default/inventory`, I have this group, but you can put whatever as per your need:

```
[server]
localhost
```

Important thing is the group name, it should match under the `default/group_vars` and `special/group_vars` file name (in my case it is `server` but in your case it can be anything):

So in `default/group_vars`, I have placed:

```
---
the_var: default
```

and in `special/group_vars`, I have placed:

```
---
the_var: not_default
```

In my test playbook(`site.yml` in this case) have:

```
---
 - hosts: all
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:
     - debug:
         msg: "{{ the_var }}"
```

Now when I call the playbook against the default inventory, got this value:

```
anansible-playbook -i default site.yml -c local                                      

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "default"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

when I call the playbook against the special inventory, got this value:

```
ansible-playbook -i special site.yml -c local

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "not_default"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

`-c local` is for localhost connection which you don't need in your live environment, I am sure you are working on remote host with ssh connection, which is default. Hope it help you.